# Rows number of SqlDataReader

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, ado.net

I'm trying to get rows count of **SqlDataReader** with SQL `COUNT()`. Because of some technical reasons I can't use a counter (increasing a variable while going forwarder). It's my SQL Statement:

```
(SELECT * FROM [Menus] WHERE MenuParent=@ID);
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowsCount FROM [Menus] WHERE MenuParent=@ID)
```

And it's my .net code: 
*(It's simple, C#ers can understand it also)*

```
While DR.Read
    If Not DR("rowsCount") Is Nothing Then
    temp &= DR("rowsCount")
    End If
    'blah blah
End While
```

It does not recognize **rowsCount**.

What's my wrong?

Whole function: (I used my own classes to connect to the DB) http://pastebin.com/YBZCvvBH

Comment: You need to show us the code before this code.  The code where you connect and execute the query and return the results into DR.

Comment: You can use a `SqlDataReader` for both. Use [`NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) to advance to the next result.

Comment: @RBarryYoung http://pastebin.com/YBZCvvBH

Comment: Please share the technical reason you cannot use a counter?

Comment: @Blam because it's a recursive function and before making decision I have to know row counts.

Comment: Then you need the count(*) statement first as you have to read in order if using NextResult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well if you realy want the recordcount inside the resultset

can do this, that seems like your query

```
    select V.rowsCount,* from [Menus]
    cross join (select COUNT(*) as rowsCount from [Menus] WHERE MenuParent=@ID)V
            WHERE MenuParent=@ID
```

or just do

```
    select COUNT(*) over () as rowsCount
    ,* from [Menus]
    WHERE MenuParent=@ID
```

Comment: There's also the (old now) COMPUTE keyword, or @@rowcount

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL statement is returning two result sets. Assuming the order of the SQL statements in your question is the same as the order you are executing, you need to process the data returned by the first query (processing the various menu options) and then execute:

```
DR.NextResult()
```

before trying to read the count.

Answer (score 0):

- Why `&=`?
- You're selecting two recordsets. If you want the count, do that first, and separately.

Comment: Why be chattier than necessary?